# Constant class attribute style according to PEP8: uppercase or lowercase?

Tags: python, class, constants, python-3.6, pep8

I really like to follow the standard coding style, but can't find an answer on this.

```
class Card:
    """Card class representing a playing card."""
    RANKS = (None, 'Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10',
             'Jack', 'Queen', 'King')
    SUITS = ('Clubs', 'Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts')

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{Card.RANKS[self.rank]} of {Card.SUITS[self.suit]}"


c = Card(1, 1)
print(c)
```

Should I write constants in class attributes all_lower_case or ALL_UPPER_CASE?
PEP8 just says that constants should be ALL_UPPER_CASE at the module level. What about classes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) makes it clear that constants should be upper-case:

> ### Constants
>
> Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include MAX_OVERFLOW and TOTAL.

Note that it just says that these are *usually* defined on a module level. But if your values should be treated as constants then make them uppercase - even if they are defined on a class level.

Answer (score 6):

Why not extract those outside of the class in the module like this:

```
from enum import Enum

class Suit(Enum):
    CLUBS = 1
    SPADES = 2
    DIAMONDS = 3
    HEARTS = 4
```

Then you could use it like:

```
Card(Rank.1, Suit.SPADES)
```

Also according to the following Python documentation it's ALL_CAPS, even inside Class. This also makes sense to me.

[More info and examples.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum)

Comment: Nice idea with the `Enum` - I really don't know why I tend to avoid / forget about them.

Comment: The Python 3.10 [documentation on enum](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/enum.html#module-enum) also has this to say, which could be considered a subtle style guide that addresses this question: "Note: Case of Enum Members 
Because Enums are used to represent constants we recommend using UPPER_CASE names for enum members, and will be using that style in our examples."